# Search inside objects (Sprocs, FUnctions, etc)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am currently using sys.syscomments to locate objects where a certain parameter exists.  Is there another method / process for doing this that would make it easier to find the objects that contain that parameter or term?

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be preferable to use the `definition` column of `sys.sql_modules` instead. `sys.syscomments` text is nvarchar(4000) so you can have issues with truncation when a definition splits across multiple rows.

```
select quotename(s.name)+'.'+quotename(o.name) as object_name, o.type_desc
    from sys.sql_modules m
        inner join sys.objects o 
            on m.object_id = o.object_id
        inner join sys.schemas s 
            on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    where m.definition like '%YourSearchText%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you're not doing this programmatically, Red Gate offers a free plug-in for SSMS called SQL Search; I'm not sure if there are other tools available.